# Changing the text of single Button within ng-repeat in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

am new to angularjs.

I want to change the text of single button within ng-repeat after successful POST request.

html code

```
<div class="row req-content-container" ng-show="selectedTopic">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 create-immediate-meeting-list-container" align="center" ng-repeat="item in allKOL">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
            <img class="profile-image-small" ng-src="{{imagesrc}}{{item.photo}}">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" valign="middle">
            <div class="row"><b><span class="pull-left">{{item.firstName}} {{item.lastName}}</span></b><br></div>
            <div class="row"><b>Speciality</b><br>{{item.speciality}} </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
            <div class="row">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="row"><b>Location</b><br>{{item.city}}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
            <div class="row">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="row"><b>Convenient Hours</b><br>{{item.fromAvailable}} to {{item.toAvailable}}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn margin-top-10 request-button-style" ng-click="sendRequest(item.id)">{{sendRequestButtonStatus}}</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

From controller, am setting the button text to "Send Request" initially and i want it to show "awaiting Request" after successful POST request, but doing this all the buttons text are changing to "awaiting Request". I tried to sort it out but couldn't, can i get any help..

Controller

```
RequestAMeetingService.immediateMeetWithDoctor(payload, function (result) {
                    if(result.success) {
                        $localStorage.immediateMeetingID = result.data.data.meeting;
                        console.log($localStorage.immediateMeetingID);
                        console.log(result.data.data);
                        $scope.closeThisDialog();
                        $scope.sendRequestButtonStatus = "Awaiting Request";
                        AlertService.addSuccess(result.data.data.message);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        AlertService.addError(result.data.data.err);
                    }
                })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case , you have to define a buttons array , with the initial text as Send Request.

```
var buttonArray = ["Send Request"]; // array should match your ng-repeat length
```

Modify your ng-click method of your button such that it sends **$index** as the second argument.Then in your success modify the text according to index.

```
$scope.buttonArray[index] = "Awaiting Request";
```

This should be your html

```
<div class="row req-content-container" ng-show="selectedTopic">
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 create-immediate-meeting-list-container" align="center" ng-repeat="item in allKOL">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
        <img class="profile-image-small" ng-src="{{imagesrc}}{{item.photo}}">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" valign="middle">
        <div class="row"><b><span class="pull-left">{{item.firstName}} {{item.lastName}}</span></b><br></div>
        <div class="row"><b>Speciality</b><br>{{item.speciality}} </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
        <div class="row">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="row"><b>Location</b><br>{{item.city}}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        <div class="row">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="row"><b>Convenient Hours</b><br>{{item.fromAvailable}} to {{item.toAvailable}}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
        <button type="button" class="btn margin-top-10 request-button-style" ng-click="sendRequest(item.id, $index)">{{ buttonArray[$index] }}</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: no.. I want to show button for each record and text changes based on the each POST Successful request and if some buttons is not clicked it should remain in initial state i.e., Send Request.. Each button will call a ngclick function sending the ID of the record